# Getting file not found exception while trying to connect with url in android studio.How to solve this?

Tags: android, wamp

I am trying to connect to mysql using wampp and the following error is thrown how to solve this?

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.2.198/login.php
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.example.mysqltest.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:46)
        at com.example.mysqltest.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: File is not available at that location.

Comment: but i am getting connection successful at http://localhost:8080/config.php

Comment: connection successful is different thing. It may be connected to local host, but file may not be available at the location.

Comment: but it is available there!?  @Chandankushwaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following possibility to occur this issue

- maybe your project or file location is not perfect
- maybe because of the port number or IP not match time of calling
- First, try to run this page in your mobile browser web browser and it will work in mobile browser then it will work in API definitely if not work then you need to change in your config

Comment: could you help me on how to do that! I will provide every detail stuck here since yesterday!

Comment: okay I will help you around 10 pm be ready with remote connection.

Comment: contact me on 9 8 98 65 47 - 73